# R - ggplot with regression line per group doesnt work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) to create a scatter plot between a predictor and response per group

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

group.nobs <- 50
group.beta0 <- c(-1., 0., 1.)
group.beta1 <- c(0.8, 1.0, 1.2)

predictor <- rnorm(n = group.nobs)
response <- c(group.beta0[1] + group.beta1[1] * predictor + rnorm(sd = 0.1, n = group.nobs),
              group.beta0[2] + group.beta1[2] * predictor + rnorm(sd = 0.1, n = group.nobs),
              group.beta0[3] + group.beta1[3] * predictor + rnorm(sd = 0.1, n = group.nobs))


df <- data.table(group=c(rep(1,group.nobs),rep(2,group.nobs),rep(3,group.nobs)), x=predictor, y=response)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)
```

but there is only 1 regression line that's plotted

[image: ggplot scatter plot with regression line]

I would like 3 regression lines for each group

thanks for the help

Comment: Side note that your group is currently a continuous variable - I guess not what you want. Would suggest using characters for group variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to group your data using the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=group, group = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)
```